# How to write $12 (N / m)^2$ in long form

Tags: exponentiation

I want to write the value $12 (N/m)^2$ in long form like "12 Newtons per meter squared". However, I believe that because of the order of operations, my long form value will be interpreted as $12 N/(m^2)$.

How should I write this value in long form? Or am I best to avoid using the long form in a situation like this?

Comment: $\frac{N}{m^2}$ is not the same as $\left(\frac{N}{m}\right)^2$.

Comment: @KM101 I was also confused, but what the OP means is that he wants to write $(N/m)^2$ in words without having it sound like $N/m^2$.

Comment: @57Jimmy is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Twelve Newtons-squared per metre-squared" is how I'd read it.